# `--crond` at the end of a command

Tags: cron

I'm just going through the logs and noticed that the system run:

```
test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond
```

as part of the daily cron jobs. I understand what this does/did except, what does the `--crond` flag at the end of the command do and why/when is this syntax used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest` is a shell script, and it takes `--crond` as an argument for controlling how often it runs the actual [`popularity-contest`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/popularity-contest.8.html) command and whether to send mails about it. This is specific to this script, and certainly not a generally available option.